# Ошибка на сервере "сбой аудита"

Tags: windows-server-2008

Windows server 2008. После взлома терминального доступа отключили учетную запись администратор, и стала возникать следующая ошибка.Подскажите что за подключение?  с ip 127.0.0.1И чем чревато отключение записи Администратор?Спасибо

> Учетной записи не удалось выполнитьвход в систему.
>
> Субъект:  ИД безопасности:        SYSTEM  Имя учетной записи:     SERVER$     Доменучетной записи:       OPTIMUS     Кодвхода:        0x3e7
>
> Тип входа:            2
>
> Учетная запись, которой не удалосьвыполнить вход:   ИДбезопасности:     NULL SID    Имя учетнойзаписи:       Администратор   Домен учетнойзаписи:       SERVER
>
> Сведения об ошибке:   Причинаошибки:       В настоящее время учетнаязапись отключена.  Состояние:          0xc000006e  Подсостояние:       0xc0000072
>
> Сведения о процессе:  Идентификаторпроцесса вызывающей стороны:  0x304  Имя процесса вызывающейстороны:  C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe
>
> Сведения о сети:  Имя рабочейстанции:  SERVER  Сетевой адресисточника:    127.0.0.1   Портисточника:        0
>
> Сведения о проверке подлинности:  Процесс входа:      User32      Пакетпроверки подлинности: Negotiate  Промежуточные службы:   -   Имя пакета(только NTLM):    -   Длина ключа:        0
>
> Данное событие возникает при неудачнойпопытке входа. Оно регистрируется накомпьютере, попытка доступа к которомубыла выполнена.
>
> Поля "Субъект" указывают на учетнуюзапись локальной системы, запросившуювход. Обычно это служба, напримерслужба "Сервер", или локальныйпроцесс, такой как Winlogon.exe илиServices.exe.
>
> В поле "Тип входа" указан типвыполненного входа. Наиболеераспространенными являются типы 2(интерактивный) и 3 (сетевой).
>
> В полях "Сведения о процессе" указано,какая учетная запись и процесс всистеме выполнили запрос на вход.
>
> Поля "Сведения о сети" указывают наисточник запроса на удаленный вход.Имя рабочей станции доступно невсегда, и в некоторых случаях это полеможет оставаться незаполненным.
>
> Поля сведений о проверке подлинностисодержат подробные данные о конкретномзапросе на вход.  - В поле "Промежуточные службы" указано, какие промежуточные службыучаствовали в данном запросе на вход.  - Поле "Имя пакета" указывает на подпротокол, использованный спротоколами NTLM.  - Поле "Длина ключа" содержит длину созданного ключа сеанса. Это полеможет иметь значение "0", если ключсеанса не запрашивался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего от этой учетки запускается служба, т.к. сервер был ранее настроен от нее, то просто удалить ее нельзя или отключить, пока не создашь учетку с админскими правами и не перенастроишь службы которые запускались от нее и естественно доступы к папкам в которые она стучится. А это адрес локальны "Сетевой адрес источника: 127.0.0.1 Порт источника: 0"